# Using C# .Net8 in VSCode seems to ignore editorconfig when running or building

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, c#-8.0, editorconfig

I have a c# solution in vs code with a .editorconfig file at the root of the project. I have had several issues with this setup.

- Building (Ctl+Shift+B) will work but running (F5 -> select dotnnet: build) will give errors for style that is ignored in the editorconfig. After the run, failure the builds will start failing.
- Editing a file will stop formatting based on the .editorconfig, usually after the building stops.
- From the Solution Explorer, right-click build on the project throwing the error, will build, however, any project referencing will fail to build with the errors.
- I build and run using the shortcuts, there are times when they will not work, but right-clicking on the project in the solution explorer will work.
- Restarting sometimes fixes the issue, other times it does not.

```
    Root/
       src/
           MySln.sln
           Foo.Host/
           Foo.Shared/
           Foo.Common/
       tools/
           add-migration.ps1
       .editorconfig
```

code --list-extensions

```
adpyke.vscode-sql-formatter
angular.ng-template
bierner.markdown-mermaid
dotjoshjohnson.xml
esbenp.prettier-vscode
gruntfuggly.todo-tree
jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager
ms-azure-devops.azure-pipelines
ms-azuretools.vscode-bicep
ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
ms-dotnettools.csdevkit
ms-dotnettools.csharp
ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime
ms-dotnettools.vscodeintellicode-csharp
ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers
ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
ms-vscode.azure-account
ms-vscode.powershell
tomoyukim.vscode-mermaid-editor
```

VSCode 1.86.2
Windows 10